# I am not able to find type error in the code?

Tags: python

1) THIS IS THE ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 14, in <module>
    customer_one_tax = customer_one_total * sales_tax
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

2)THIS IS ONE VARIABLE:

```
sales_tax = '.088'
```

3) ANOTHER VARIBLE CUSTOMER_ONE TOTAL IS AN UPDATED VARIABLE WHOSE LAST UPDATE WAS:

```
customer_one_total += luxurious_lamp_price
```

Comment: `customer_one_tax = customer_one_total * float(sales_tax)` ? And you need to post correct code.

Comment: Provide a code snippet too

Comment: As it looks you are are trying to do mathematical calculations on non-numeric types. Both variables are sequences (strings, list, tuples...). While some programming languages allow calculation with numbers in strings (and create a lot of confusions at the same time), Python does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like sales_tax is a string. '.088'--> `str`.  Maybe try .088

Comment: Thanks for help. It has been 2 days since I started learning programming online, I was really confused. You solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Akash If I solved the problem, can you mark my answer appropriately?

Comment: I have clicked on accept this answer but I not able to cast vote becuase my reputation is below 15. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear:

`can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`

Your `sales_tax = '.088'` is a `string` instead of a `number`

And:

```py
>>>3*'.88'
'.88.88.88'
>>>'3'*'.88'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Seem your `customer_one_total` isn't a 'number' too

My suggestion is `float()`

```py
customer_one_total += float(luxurious_lamp_price)
customer_one_tax = customer_one_total * float(sales_tax)
```

Comment: Thanks you. Actually I was using 'commas' in the numbers, that's why it wasn't working like a number.